# Is The Simple Predicate (Verb) Sinking Or Colliding?

Tags: grammar, predicate

The sinking of the ship after it collided with an iceberg resulted in many safety reforms.

What is the simple predicate? Is it Sinking? Or is it colliding?

Answer (score 1):

The verb in the sentence is *resulted*.

You can parse the sentence like this, where *[X]* is the subject of the sentence:

> The [X] **resulted** in many safety reforms.

In short:

> The [sinking of the ship after it collided with an iceberg] **resulted** in many safety reforms.

It's the same general construction as this:

> The [fire] **resulted** in many safety reforms.

Answer (score 0):

Neither are the predicate verb. "Sinking" is used as a noun (gerund)... it fou ere not sure, notice the article before it. "After it collided" is a dependent clause.

Look for another verb in that sentence.